# If an exradius of a triangle is the sum of the two other exradii and the inradius, then the triangle is ...

Tags: trigonometry, triangles

> In a triangle $ABC$, if an exradius is the sum of the two other exradii and the inradius, the triangle is
>
> 1. equilateral
> 2. isosceles
> 3. scalene
> 4. right-angled

I've tried multiple times, but this is the most simplified expression I've got:
$$r_1 = r_2 + r_3 + r$$
$$sX\tan\frac A2=sX\tan\frac B2+sX\tan\frac C2+(s-a)\tan\frac A2$$
$$sX\tan\frac A2=sX\tan\frac B2+sX\tan\frac C2+sX\tan\frac A2-aX\tan\frac A2$$
$$aX\tan\frac A2=sX\tan\frac B2+sX\tan\frac C2$$
I could not go further.

Comment: Thanks -Parcly, I have been struggling for last half an hour to edit this post. I am new to this site.

Comment: Welcome to Math SE! You can insert math using $\LaTeX$.

Answer (score 1):

In right $\triangle ABC$, with $\angle C=90^\circ$, and standard definitions for $a,b,c,s,r_a,r_b,r_c$, we have
\begin{align*}
r_a&=s-b\\
r_b&=s-a\\
r_c&=s.
\end{align*}
These follow from the fact that the distance from a vertex to the point of tangency between a side and the opposite excircle is always $s$. Also, we have $$r=\frac{a+b-c}{2}=s-c.$$
The proof is a fun little exercise involving Equal Tangents. Then, $$r_c=s=3s-2s=(s-b)+(s-a)+(s-c)=r_a+r_b+r,$$
so the answer is $\boxed{\mathbf{(4)}\text{ right-angled}}$.